# How can I access a hover state in reactjs?

Tags: hover, reactjs

I have a sidenav with a bunch of basketball teams. So I would like to display something different for each team when one of them is being hovered over. Also, I am using Reactjs so if I could have a variable that I could pass to another component that would be awesome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [a hover button in react.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072196/a-hover-button-in-react-js)

Answer (score 309, accepted):

React components expose all the standard Javascript mouse events in their top-level interface.  Of course, you can still use `:hover` in your CSS, and that may be adequate for some of your needs, but for the more advanced behaviors triggered by a hover you'll need to use the Javascript. So to manage hover interactions, you'll want to use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`.  You then attach them to handlers in your component like so:

```
<ReactComponent
    onMouseEnter={() => this.someHandler}
    onMouseLeave={() => this.someOtherHandler}
/>
```

You'll then use some combination of state/props to pass changed state or properties down to your child React components.

Comment: okay, I think that will work. let me test it out. also, how can I pass this variable to a different/not connected component?

Comment: That actually gets tricky, React doesn't exactly provide for that.  In the architecture of a web app, that gets into the global, over-arching communication methodology chosen.  Many people would choose an event-bus type solution, where some global event manager is posting and receiving events in disparate components.  These event messages would contain the data you want to pass as arguments.  This is what Facebook suggests in their docs on the topic: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Comment: One thing I want to add is that `onMouseEnter` `onMouseLeave` are DOM events. They won't work on a custom `ReactComponent`, you will need to pass the events down as a prop and bind these events to a DOM element in that `ReactComponent`, like `<div onMouseOver={ () => this.props.onMouseOver }>`

Comment: https://github.com/cht8687/react-hover can achive this job easilly

Answer (score 46):

ReactJs defines the following synthetic events for mouse events:

```
onClick onContextMenu onDoubleClick onDrag onDragEnd onDragEnter onDragExit
onDragLeave onDragOver onDragStart onDrop onMouseDown onMouseEnter onMouseLeave
onMouseMove onMouseOut onMouseOver onMouseUp
```

As you can see there is no hover event, because browsers do not  define a hover event natively.

You will want to add handlers for onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave for hover behavior.

[ReactJS Docs - Events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)

Answer (score 18):

For having hover effect you can simply try this code

```
import React from "react";
  import "./styles.css";

    export default function App() {

      function MouseOver(event) {
        event.target.style.background = 'red';
      }
      function MouseOut(event){
        event.target.style.background="";
      }
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <button onMouseOver={MouseOver} onMouseOut={MouseOut}>Hover over me!</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Or if you want to handle this situation using useState() hook then you can try this piece of code

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";


export default function App() {
   let [over,setOver]=React.useState(false);

   let buttonstyle={
    backgroundColor:''
  }

  if(over){
    buttonstyle.backgroundColor="green";
  }
  else{
    buttonstyle.backgroundColor='';
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button style={buttonstyle}
      onMouseOver={()=>setOver(true)} 
      onMouseOut={()=>setOver(false)}
      >Hover over me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Both of the above code will work for hover effect but first procedure is easier to write and understand

Answer (score 4):

I know the accepted answer is great but for anyone who is looking for a hover like feel you can use `setTimeout` on `mouseover` and save the handle in a map (of let's say list ids to setTimeout Handle). On `mouseover` clear the handle from setTimeout and delete it from the map

```
onMouseOver={() => this.onMouseOver(someId)}
onMouseOut={() => this.onMouseOut(someId)
```

And implement the map as follows:

```
onMouseOver(listId: string) {
  this.setState({
    ... // whatever
  });

  const handle = setTimeout(() => {
    scrollPreviewToComponentId(listId);
  }, 1000); // Replace 1000ms with any time you feel is good enough for your hover action
  this.hoverHandleMap[listId] = handle;
}

onMouseOut(listId: string) {
  this.setState({
    ... // whatever
  });

  const handle = this.hoverHandleMap[listId];
  clearTimeout(handle);
  delete this.hoverHandleMap[listId];
}
```

And the map is like so,

```
hoverHandleMap: { [listId: string]: NodeJS.Timeout } = {};
```

I prefer `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` because it also applies to all the children in the `HTMLElement`. If this is not required you may use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work for OP because they wanted a variable but for those who just want a UI hover effect it's usually easier to stick with CSS.

Below example will reveal a delete button when an item is hovered over:

```
<div className="revealer">
  <div>
    {itemName}
  </div>
  <div className="hidden">
    <Btn label="Delete"/>
  </div>
</div>


.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.revealer:hover .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

Parent div has `revealer` class. When it's hovered over, it'll reveal the `hidden` div. Hidden div must be nested inside revealer div.

Answer (score 2):

Using useState,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [ishover,sethover]=useState(false);

  function MouseOver() {
    sethover(true);
  }
  function MouseOut() {
    sethover(false);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button
      style={{backgroundColor: ishover?"black":null}}
        onMouseOver={MouseOver}
        onMouseOut={MouseOut}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please add some more details do not post code only answers

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own component logics using those events which stolli and BentOnCoding suggested above, or use the module named [react-hover](https://github.com/cht8687/react-hover)

> if I could have a variable that I could pass to another component that would be awesome.

then you can simply wrap another component

```js
 <ReactHover options={optionsCursorTrueWithMargin}>
  <Trigger type="trigger">
    <TriggerComponent />
  </Trigger>
  <Hover type="hover">
    <HoverComponent />
  </Hover>
</ReactHover>
```

or your plain HTML:

```js
<ReactHover options={optionsCursorTrueWithMargin}>
  <Trigger type="trigger">
    <h1 style={{ background: '#abbcf1', width: '200px' }}> Hover on me </h1>
  </Trigger>
  <Hover type="hover">
    <h1> I am hover HTML </h1>
  </Hover>
</ReactHover>
```

demo code here: [demo](http://cht8687.github.io/react-hover/example/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React and Material-ui, you can inject css with the `sx` Props:

```
const HoverTable = () => {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ '&:hover .hoverChild': { opacity: 1 } }}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          Column1
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Box className="hoverChild" sx={{ opacity: 0 }}>
            <Button variant="contained">Button</Button>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default HoverTable
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try to implement below code. Hover functionality can be acheived with Tooltip.
Please refer below code and link for clarity
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/

```
import * as React from 'react';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

export default function BasicTooltip() {
    return (
    <Tooltip title="Delete">
      <IconButton>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
    );
    }
```