# How to change the icon of a button when it is clicked, button already has a on click event

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

I want to change the icon on the button whenever it is clicked, The button has onClick event to add product to basket.

```
      <Button
          style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
          type="primary"
          icon={<img src={plusCart} />}
          onClick={addToBasket}
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

const addToBasket = () => {
  ...
  setButtonClicked(true);
};

...

<Button
  ...
  icon={<img src={buttonClicked ? someIcon : plusCart} />}
  onClick={addToBasket}
/>
```

Comment: If this works for you please click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also, see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: how can we do this for cursor hover, change icons of a button on hover in react ??

Comment: @tiedantebreak Remove `onClick` prop and try this props `onMouseEnter={() => setButtonClicked(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setButtonClicked(false)}`

Comment: @tiedantebreak Let me know if it works.

Comment: yes it worked thanks

Comment: @tiedantebreak Greate, don't forgot to upvote the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean state for this, maybe like so:

```
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

const addToBasket = () => {
  setButtonClicked(true);
  // your code..

};

<Button
          style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
          type="primary"
          icon={buttonClicked ? <img src={otherIcon}/> : <img src={plusCart}/>}
          onClick={addToBasket}
        />
```

Comment: how can we do this for cursor hover, change icons of a button on hover in react ?? –

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125708/how-can-i-access-a-hover-state-in-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

You can store information if button was clicked in `useState` hook and onClick change this state:

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false)

return(
 <Button
          style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
          type="primary"
          icon={<img src={clicked ? plusCart : minusCart} />}
          onClick={(e)=>{
           setClicked(true);
           addToBasket(e);}}
        />
)
```

Comment: how can we do this for cursor hover, change icons of a button on hover in react ?? –