# Add Underline When Hover in React and CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

How do I add a underline in text-decoration when hovering the text?
Seems this is correct but it still doesn't work

[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-ramanujan-51m44k?file=/src/App.js)

```
       <span
        style={{
          color: "red",
          cursor: "pointer",
          "& :hover": {
            textDecoration: "underline"
          }
        }}
      >
        Click this.
      </span>
```

Comment: `& :hover` would apply to a hovered _descendant_ of the current element. You want `&:hover`

Comment: You are using less syntax, sure that's implemented in your project?

Comment: @CBroe. Tried `&:hover` but same thing. underline doesnt appear

Comment: Then you probably don't have less pre compiler. Use a regular className with some css.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access a hover state in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125708/how-can-i-access-a-hover-state-in-reactjs)

Comment: Try the code I put in the answers @Joseph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `style` property doesn't support selectors.

You need to move your logic into a `<style>` element or a `<link>`ed stylesheet.

There are plenty of React-friendly libraries for generating them on-the-fly for you. [Styled Components](https://styled-components.com/) is a popular tool for this which supports the SCSS syntax you are (almost — you have a rogue space after the `&`) using.

```
import { styled } from 'styled-components';

const MySpan = styled.span`
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
`;
```

and then

```
<MySpan>Click this.</MySpan>
```

However, span elements are not designed to be interactive. They are not announced as clickable by screen readers and you can't tab to them if you aren't using a mouse. This is a major accessibility barrier. If you want something for the user to click on, use a link (if you are linking somewhere) or a button (otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/making-sense-of-react-inline-styles-f521d9c511b3):

> There has been plenty of valid points made that react inline style is not a good idea. No support for CSS selectors like “:hover”, “:active” “:focus”, “:before” and “:after”, media queries, nor for SCSS syntax, to name a few.

Just use a css file and implement it there with `class:hover`

Answer (score 1):

try this, I Tried it and it works.

App.js:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span
        style={{
          color: "red",
          cursor: "pointer"
        }}
      >
        Click this.
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

style.css:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

span:hover {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
  color: "red";
}
```