# How to add here hover that when hover then download button show other wise not show

Tags: reactjs

I want to add hover on every render row and when hover the download button will be shown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrXKG.png)

Comment: did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125708/how-can-i-access-a-hover-state-in-reactjs)? You can make the button active with class.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with css like

```
.row-with-download:hover button {
display: block;
}
```

or like

```
const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);


<Row onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}> 

{isShown && <button/>}
```