# Check if mouse is over a specific react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to stop some behaviour based on a condition if a mouse is hovering over a particular react component in my app.

I can only find old answers referencing jQuery and JS vanilla. Is there another way to do this? Or is it not acceptable?

Here is the component I interested in determining if the mouse is over:

```
<ContentRightHandSide offset={bannerHidden ? 80 : 120}>
            <ContentTitle>
              Activity
              <img
                style={{
                  display: "inline",
                  position: "relative",
                  marginLeft: "20px",
                  width: "35px",
                }}
                src={calendarIcon}
              />
            </ContentTitle>

            {authStatus === "authenticated" ? (
              <ShareLogs
                linkShareLogs={activeShareLogs}
                isBannerHidden={bannerHidden}
                hovered={hoveredNode}
                selected={selectedNode}
              />
            ) : (
              <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                <img
                  src={blurredScreenLinks}
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "24px",
                    position: "relative",
                    margin: "0 auto",
                    width: "100%",
                  }}
                />

                <button
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#F7F1FF",
                    color: "#35373B",
                    position: "absolute",
                    fontFamily: "lato",
                    left: "0",
                    right: "0",
                    marginLeft: "auto",
                    marginRight: "auto",
                    width: "320px",
                    top: "100px",
                    padding: "0px 20px",
                    display: "flex",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    borderRadius: "60px",
                  }}
                  onClick={handleSignInClick}
                >
                  <img
                    style={{
                      display: "inline",
                      position: "relative",
                      width: "80px",
                      cursor: "pointer",
                      margin: "-5px",
                    }}
                    src={slackIcon}
                  />
                  <span style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>
                    Lorem Ipsum                  
</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
          </ContentRightHandSide>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access a hover state in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125708/how-can-i-access-a-hover-state-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1):

You can define hover events like this in React, similar to how you would handle `onClick`.

```
<Component
onMouseEnter={handleSomething}
onMouseLeave={handleSomething}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can determine if the mouse is currently over a React component, but how to "stop some behavior" depends on how your behavior runs.

If you can make your behavior dependent on some state variable, you can give the React component a handler that sets the state on `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` events:

```
const [isMouseOver, setIsMouseOver] = useState(false)
...
<ContentRightHandSide
    onMouseEnter={() => setIsMouseOver(true)}
    onMouseLeave={() => setIsMouseOver(false)}
    offset={bannerHidden ? 80 : 120}
>
...
</ContentRightHandSide>
```

The handler you give to the component doesn't need to set a state variable either, it can perform whatever logic is needed to change your behavior.

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9dwfjLu/) demonstrates that behavior in a class-based component.

The events you might be interested in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event

There is [a section about handling events in the official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) that might give you more ideas.